# Should my Android TV module have the same package name as my Android Mobile module?

Tags: android

Basically, I'm on the verge of releasing my Android TV app which is a bit of an extension from my mobile app. My Android TV app's package name is `co.id.example.tv`, and my mobile app's package name is `com.astra.example` (both aren't actual names, but the essence is still the same).

Complicating things further is the Google Sign In that I have to use for the Android TV app. Having different package names means I have to create a new project in the Google API console, while having the same package name means changing the tracking analytics' parameters to determine whether the user interaction is from the TV or the mobile app.

In the end, should I change my Android TV app's package name to be the same as the mobile app's package name for distribution?